# Control and shift keys not working [pressed together]

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-keyboard

I have a weird problem with my logitech deluxe 250 keyboard. When I press shift key control key is pressed automatically and vice versa. No stick keys have been set up. I tried opening on screen keyboard and I can see both control and shift key being pressed automatically when I press only one of them.
I presumed it to be a hardware issue and took out the control key but still same issue occurs. Please advise

Comment: I seems your Shift key is also broken...

Comment: precisely. that is why am not able to capitalize the words. thanks for the edit nifle